# Angular Navigate Routing between parent and child

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, angular8

I have 2 components with parent and child relations. In the parent component, I have images which on click should navigate to child component. Following is my code, the URL in the browser is changing but the page isn't navigating.

Routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent, children: [
      { path: 'child', component: ChildComponent}
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

HTML

```
<section>
    <img src="imagePath" alt="" (click)="gotoProfile()">
</section>
<div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

TS

```
gotoProfile() {
    this.route.navigate(['/parent/child']);
}
```

The navigation is working only when I use boolean variables to display hide on button click (which is not a good practise), as below. Using boolean values after navigating is throwing some problem, on click of back button in child component the parent component is not loading.

TS

```
 gotoProfile() {
      this.hideParentDiv = true;
      this.route.navigate(['/parent/child']);
    }
```

HTML

```
 <section *ngIf="hideParentDiv ">
        <img src="imagePath" alt="" (click)="gotoProfile()">
    </section>
    <div *ngIf="!hideParentDiv ">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

Can anybody help me with this, any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Firstly what you mean about the "display hide" on the button. Do you hide the button when its clicked or the images. Also please provide your router module code and some code of the child component

Comment: @JoCarrasco display and hiding the parent and child components, on clicking the image as it should navigate to child component(as I am having navigation problem I am hiding the parent html here)

Comment: @JoCarrasco I have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **router-outlet** is tag used to render the components. You **should not** hide it.It's like blocking a door before trying to get in. If you want to **"hide"** the elements, then you should move the router-outlet up in the navigation hierarchy. What this means is that you should make "Page of Images to Click" and "Page of Detail Image" siblings in the router. Like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: ExampleComponent, children: [
      { path: 'images-page', component: ImagesComponent },
      { path: 'image-detail-page', component: ImageDetailComponent}
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
];
```